# Django Signal not adding user to a group

Tags: django, signals

I am trying to add a user to a group when the user is created. I have seen a few different ways to accomplish similar things with signals but nothing I am trying has seemed to work.

In the shell, I ran Group.objects.get(name='User') to make sure that the group was being recognized.

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def add_user_to_user_group(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    try:
        if created:
            instance.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name='User'))
    except Group.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

This part I am very unsure of, I have seen a few different ways people have done this part. One tutorial did it this way but I am not sure what just importing the signals would do

app.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'User'

    def ready(self):
        import User.signals
```

Comment: Do you have any errors there?

Comment: No errors just won't add the new user to the group. I also removed the try except to make sure it wasn't erroring and passing without alerting.

Comment: You are adding Group to a User, not User to group. After that script try `your_user.groups.all()`, is it empty queryset? Could you show User and Group models? And how do you check that it's empty?

Comment: If each User should by added to the User group, have you considered to move your receiver inside your models.py and remove the try/except clause?

Comment: Is there a reason you think the location would make a difference? I thought the recommendation was to create a signals file. I will have to create more signals too once it is all said and done. I also did remove the try/except clause after adding it here to test and it didn't change anything.